# sqlservr.exe always reading SBSMonitoring.mdf

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I'm having an issue with my sqlservr.exe which is always reading the SBSMonitoring.mdf, around 50MB/sec. I saw that in Reliability and Performance mmc. I don't think my hard drive love it... and it slows down my server.
We have a SBS 2008.

I found nothing about it, help me please :)
Thanks.

Comment: It's not mysql.exe it's going to be sqlservr.exe.  MySQL is a totally different product which can't access SQL Server database files.

Comment: oops yeah that's it

Comment: Something seems odd here as that's an awful lot of IO for SBS monitoring, what's the disk queue length on the drive?  Does the page for sbs monitoring show up at all?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and posted to Microsoft's SBS Community forum.  I was directed to [Microsoft Knowledge Base article 981939](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981939) which seems to have fixed my problem without disabling the monitoring.

The article includes a powershell script to reduce the amount of monitoring data that is kept from 90 days to 30 days and adds some indexes and statistics to the database.

Answer (score 0):

SBS Monitoring looks like a beast. I've found two links for you to look at:

- This one from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs)
- This one from the [MVP site](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2008/08/25/deep-dive-into-sbs-2008-monitoring-and-reporting.aspx)

I hope these help. You might want to look at either turning this off, or configuring it to use fewer resources. 50MB/s sounds like your drive is exclusively doing this monitoring.

EDIT: Here's another link. This may be more useful:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708152(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I must add that I steer clear of SBS altogether. Whomever thought it was a good idea should be shot. Exchange needs its own box, period.

Comment: Thx but I didn't find anything usefull :(

Comment: That's why the new SBS lets you use 2 or 3 servers to host everything. They are finely getting closer.

Comment: @mrdenny: When a marketing department specs a technical solution, it's going to end in tears.

Comment: @Ransolph I've vented to a few people at Microsoft about that issue on a few products.  They all agree, but are overruled, by Marketing people.

Comment: All of these links are dead. This is why we frown on link-only answers folks.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't using the monitoring disable it.  It sounds like you are monitoring a ton of stuff.  You can also check the database in SQL Server and make sure that it's not set to autoclose the database which would add to the problem.

Comment: I don't really know how to disable the monitoring thing, how can I choose exactly what to monitor ?

Comment: @Bastien: I've edited my original answer with a link to Technet. That looks like it may help.

Comment: @Randolph that looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: It just shows how to monitor the server, Reliability and Performance mmc in SBS 08 do it all for me. I saw that problem thanks to it, but how to resolve it ? :(

Comment: I don't have SBS so I'm going off what I can find (which isn't much at the moment).  Is there any way to remove some metrics from the monitor?

Comment: It's just for reporting, I can't configure it with it.